# Flash Whiteboard: Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, media, whiteboard

I'm looking for a flash Actionscript 3 tutorial on how to create a whiteboard application with flash media server 3.5. Please anybody have any ideas where I can start looking for this information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Search for the articles:

1. Using the Whiteboard component
2. Creating a Whiteboard Application with Macromedia Flash Communication Server MX

My first answer so no link allowed for me