# Flash AS3 Chat/Whiteboard Integration

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm currently looking into building a multiuser whiteboard that has a chat as well. I'm finding myself confused as I plan the two together.

When I build them, will they work as two separate entities in the same file or will they need to interact with one another? I'm not sure if that makes sense, I'm confused, so I apologize.

I've been searching for a tutorial on how to build an interactive whiteboard with a chat, but I can't find one and I've been at the search for three or so hours. I've found how to build an interactive whiteboard at CreativeCow, but it doesn't use a chat.

To sum it up, these are my questions:

1. Will a multiuser whiteboard need to interact with a chat in the same file?
2. Does anyone know a tutorial that uses as3 to build a multiuser whiteboard with a chat?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904752/flash-whiteboard-actionscript-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a tough job to do, you need lot of skills, a responsive server technology (java maybe)... it would require months of work from an experienced developper.

If you look for a tutorial I guess you are not an experienced developper.

I advise you to look for a ready to use application (you'll find them easely).

Comment: I actually found what I needed, for the most part. Enough resources to get me started anyway. In the meantime, I'll be using a third-party app until my own is developed.

It's not always best to assume someone is an inexperienced developer because they look for tutorials. Tutorials aren't simply for beginners - they answer the how-to of varying levels.

I'll mark your answer as the correct answer, since it's the temporary solution I've decided to use. 

Also, it can be done using Flash, but I'll be using server-side with a Flash UI.

Thank you and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

I can guide you for the same. Multiuser Whiteboard with Chat....Please give me your whole requriement . I will give you flow of development and guideline for whole development ...its very easy to develop...

Comment: I'll be building a whiteboard that's capable of text and drawing. It may also have image share. To the side will be a chat area. That's the whole requirement. It's rather simple, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Comment: Let me clarify that a bit more.

Either user will be capable of writing text on the whiteboard. They will also be able to draw lines and shapes, change the color of the text/line/shape, change the size of the lines/font, and resize the shapes. They also need to be able to erase. An undo function may be nice as well, but not necessary with the erase option. A chat is available for better communication, but is only capable of entering text. Nothing extra.

Comment: I've actually built the chat already. I used PHP and Flash in order to do so and I've set it up so it can be dropped into any other application. 

Now all I need to do is figure out how to build a whiteboard so it can be used by multiple users.